# access vba using a variable for field name

Tags: vba, ms-access, variables, field

I Have a form with a query in the RecordSource that works.
I am trying to use a variable to get the value in a field.
There are several company names that I pull from labels on the form to make up the field name.

This works...

```
MsgBox ([M1SS Emp Nbr])
```

I get the company name from the form label in line below. It is M1SS.
I cant get it to work using a variable containing [M1SS Emp Nbr]. I get the string value not the value in the field.

```
strCurrent_Company_Name = Eval("Forms!StartUp.Label_Company_" & Int_Company_Chosen & ".Caption") 
'This returns M1SS

strCurrent_Company_Emp_Nbr_Field = strCurrent_Company_Name & " Emp Nbr"
'This returns M1SS Emp Nbr.

MsgBox (strCurrent_Company_Emp_Nbr_Field) 
'This returns M1SS Emp Nbr
```

I also tried:

```
MsgBox ("[" & strCurrent_Company_Emp_Nbr_Field & "]") 
'This returns [M1SS Emp Nbr] instead of the value.
```

And:

```
strCurrent_Company_Emp_Nbr_Field = "([" & strCurrent_Company_Name & " Emp Nbr].Value)"

strCurrent_Company_Emp_Nbr_Field = Eval("(Me.[" & strCurrent_Company_Name & " Emp Nbr].Value)")
```

I hope this was easy to understand. 
I have worked with access VBA as a hobby. Thanks for any help in advance!

Comment: you should properly format your code- https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help

Answer (score 0):

This ought to work:

```
MsgBox Controls(Controls("Label_Company_" & Int_Company_Chosen).Caption & " Emp Nbr").Value
```